# Movimentar controles button em uma aplicação Windows Formulários dentro de um contêiner panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um formulário com três controles botões, são eles: btnVendas, btnFuncionarios, btnConfig. E eles estão alinhados dentro de um contêiner Panel. Eu preciso que estes botões possam ser clicados e sustentados pelo ponteiro do mouse para que o usuário possa colocá-los no lugar que preferir somente os arrastando de uma posição à outra, sendo o espaço de deslocamento permitido somente dentro da área do contêiner Panel que os engloba.

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407068/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-button-from-one-panel-to-another-panel) tem uma resposta boa demonstrando como fazer drag-n-drop, caso queira.

Comment: Bem legal o conteúdo do link, porém, há algumas diferenças, eu aqui quero somente movimentar os botões arrastando com o ponteiro do mouse, e assim posicioná-los em uma localização diferente da inicial dentro ainda do mesmo espaço, no caso, dentro do panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AllowDrop = true;
    panel1.DragEnter += Panel1_DragEnter;
    panel1.DragDrop += Panel1_DragDrop;            
    button2.MouseDown += Button2_MouseDown;
}


private void Button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    button2.DoDragDrop(button2, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void Panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = ((Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button)));
    var point = panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    btn.Left = point.X;
    btn.Top = point.Y;
}

private void Panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```